# switch homebrew source install to bottle

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

for some reason, I don't know why, on my laptop brew is using the source of mongodb and compiles it on every update and on my iMac it's using the way more convenient bottle install.

is there any way to switch it to the bottle install?

Comment: Can you share the output of `brew install mongodb`?

Comment: Warning: mongodb-3.2.10 already installed :D

Comment: Can you share the output of `brew remove mongodb; brew install mongodb` for the laptop and for the iMac?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles) There are different reasons why a bottle is not installed:

- user requests it by specifying `--build-from-source`,
- if the formula requests it (with `pour_bottle?`),
- if any options are specified during installation (bottles are all compiled with default options),
- if the bottle is not up to date (e.g. lacking a checksum)
- if the bottle’s cellar is not :any nor equal to the current HOMEBREW_CELLAR.

It is also possible that the OS on you laptop is different from OS on you iMac and the mongodb formulae does not have a bottle your laptop's OS.